# Can't understand the meaning of this runtime comparison table

Tags: javascript, runtime, face-detection

I've got javascript face detection library on [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect). The table below is the **runtime** comparison of some similiar face detection libraries which I can't understand what it means. Someone please help me to understanding this comparison table.

[image: Compared table]

Comment: Where did you find this table? Can you provide a url?

Comment: i've posted that on my question above, here it is if you need: https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the author but my interpretation is as follows. The first column header shows two browsers, Chrome and Firefox (Chrome 40 / FF 35)  The other columns show results for the given headers but one for each browser.

So in the Detections/Second column in the first row it is 17.5 detections per seconds for Chrome and 16.9 detections per second for Firefox.

In the second column there were 50 detections made by Chrome and 50 detections made by Firefox. In the third column Chrome took 2.86 seconds to do its 50 detections. Firefox took 2.96 second to do its detections.

For Chrome 50 detections/2.86 seconds = 17.482 detections per second. In the chart that is rounded up to 17.5 detections per second.

The other rows follow the same pattern. Hope that helps.

Comment: oh i see know, i dont realize that Detection column is for both Chrome and Mozilla because it using "/". Thank you for your helpful answer, now it make a sense :)

Comment: Your interpretation of the comparison table is correct. The table is more readable now ;)